# Probability that x distinct numbers are all present in an array of size n?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-theory, problem-solving

I have currently finished my semester and I´m trying to learn some stuff on my own. Recently I stumbled upon a problem:

*What is the probability that some **x** **distinct** numbers are all present in an array of size **n**, if the array **can** contain only numbers from this range **x**, with **n** much greater than **x**?*

*Example*

**x** = 3 (1, 2, 3)

**n** = 10

array= {1, 2, 2, 1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3}

Maybe it´s just an easy problem in probability, but just out of curiosity, can someone enlighten me if there is a formula for this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is known as the 'coupon collector's problem'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like a good place to apply the Principle of Inclusion/Exclusion.

Let's say the sequence of $n$ numbers has "property $i$" if $i$ does not appear in the sequence, for $1 \le i \le x$.  Define $S_j$ to be the total of all the probabilities of the sequences that have $j$ of the properties (i.e., the sequence is missing $j$ numbers), for $1 \le j \le x-1$.  Since there are $\binom{x}{j}$ ways to select the set of $j$ missing numbers, and the probability of a sequence of $n$ numbers not containing any of those numbers is $((x-j)/x)^n$,
$$S_j = \binom{x}{j} \left( \frac{x-j}{x} \right)^n$$

By Inclusion/Exclusion, the probability of a sequence with none of the properties, i.e. a sequence with no missing numbers, is
$$p_0 = 1 + \sum_{j=1}^{x-1} (-1)^j S_j$$

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all numbers have equal probability and  independently chosen, then the multinomial distribution can be used.   A typical term looks like $\frac{1}{x^n}\frac{n!}{a_1!a_2!...a_x!}$, where $\sum_{i=1}^xa_i=n$ and all $a_i\ge 0$. The probability you want is the sum over all terms where none of the $a_i=0$.

For computational purposes, it will be easier to get the sum over all terms with at least one $a_i=0$ and subtract from $1$.

Comment: Thanks very much!